# Installing scoop bucket with python?

Tags: python, scoop-installer

I want to try to install an scoop bucket using python, but i am not having any luck on how to do it.
I want to try to do some Twitch API coding (ref. https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/ and https://github.com/twitchdev/twitch-cli), but in the steps on how to do it, it says that i need to run

```
scoop bucket add twitch https://github.com/twitchdev/scoop-bucket.git
scoop install twitch-cli
```

But over pip i can't get the library installed.

Is it possible to do it over pip?

Comment: Did you read this already? https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Scoop#installation

Comment: I can install it from the powershell - which i did, but i still can't access the library in my python scripts. Am i suppose to install scoop to a different location?

Comment: Which library are you trying to access in your Python scripts?

Comment: https://github.com/twitchdev/twitch-cli from this link
Mainly this: 
scoop bucket add twitch https://github.com/twitchdev/scoop-bucket.git
scoop install twitch-cli

Comment: I'm not sure what all of this has to do with Python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: twitch-cli is not a Python library, if you search for 'twitch api python library' you might find what you're looking for.